# Can I set the default value of the cookie set by mod_session?

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf

(This question pertains to a containerized version of the httpd server version 2.4.57.)

I am required to log visitor activity by a session token using mod_session (see: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/apache_server_2.4_windows_site/2021-09-27/finding/V-214378).  Here is my setup in httpd.conf.

```
<IfModule session_module>
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/;httponly;secure;
    SessionMaxAge 600
</IfModule>
```

This configuration will send a cookie named *session* whose value is equivalent to this `expiry=123456789`.  The documentation for this module (see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_session.html).  The expiry value is not a unique session ID.  I also read about mod_unique_id, which generates a unique ID *for each request* within an environment variable, so that does not seem to fit the bill.

How can I set the value of the session cookie to a unique ID?

Note: I cannot manipulate the cookie using Javascript since my requirement demands it be `httponly`.

Comment: It is unique per visitor.

Comment: Hello again, vidarlo.  Do you mean the environment variable is unique per visitor?

Comment: Yes, the session cookie is unique per visitor. That's the point; to maintain sessions...

Comment: @vidarlo My contention with your comment is that you're saying the *cookie* is unique per visitor; however, it changes every time the *same* visitor makes a request.  It should not change unless the visitor changes (which it isn't because I'm the only visitor).

Comment: How have you verified that it changes for same visitor? It should not. When a cookie with the value is present Apache should stick to it.

Comment: I was able to verify it is changing by observing it in my browser's web dev tools and the logs.